# Billing address in Account Object

Tags: customization

Is it possible to change the standard billing adress state field to accept picklist values.

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce has a recently introduced [State and Country Picklists](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&language=en_US) feature that can be turned on in an org. Note that the state and country fields on both Account and Contact are affected, but in general that is a good thing so users see the same behaviour for fields of the same type.